# Array item could not be found in php shopping cart

Tags: php, arrays, session, multidimensional-array, shopping-cart

I am struggling with a weird situation here with arrays in PHP. I am trying to create a simple cart using a session variable.

Problem:

When the cart is empty, the program creates a new product with the `itemid` and `qty` variables when a product is added to cart (as required). It also does same when other new products are added.

It also is able to update the quantity of products if added again (as required).

But the problem here is it never finds the 1st product I add, so whenever I add that product again, it stacks the product every time and does not update the quantity of the product. Whereas for other products other than 1st, it acts as expected.

eg. when product A is added to empty cart, it adds `itemid` as A and qty = 1. When the product A is added **again** to an empty cart, it adds the `itemid` as A and `qty=1` **again** (does not do qty=2). If I add B, C or others repeatedly it updates their `qty` as required

```
<?php
public function addinTable($id){
      $this->loadModel('Carts');

    /////////inserting into the cart table//////////7
      $item = $this->Products->get($id);
      $session = $this->request->session();

      $allProducts = $session->read('Cart');

    if(null!=$allProducts){
        echo "<br>if(allProducts is NOT EMPTY)<br>";
         if(array_search($id,array_column($allProducts, 'itemid'))){
            //if the id is already in list
                 echo "<br><b>ITEM Is IN the list already</b>";
            $key = array_search($id,array_column($allProducts, 'itemid'));
                echo "<br> key is ", $key;
            $newqty = debug($allProducts[$key]['qty']);
                echo "<br> new qty +1 = ".$newqty+=1;
                debug($allProducts[$key]['qty']++);
            $session->write('Cart',$allProducts);
               debug( $session->read('Cart'));
        }
        else{
          echo"<br><b>The id is not found but cart is not empty</b>";
            $allProducts[] = array('itemid'=>$id,
                                    'qty' => 1
                                  );
            debug( $session->read('Cart'));
        }

    }
     else{///////////if cart is empty at first
         echo"<br><b>The  cart is  empty</b>";
       $allProducts[] = array('itemid'=>$id,'qty' => 1);

          debug($allProducts[0]);
          debug($allProducts);
          debug($allProducts[0]['itemid']);

        //  if(array_search($id,array_column($allProducts, 'itemid'))==true){echo "hello";}
          $session->write('Cart',$allProducts);
                 debug($session->read('Cart'));
                     }
            $session->write('Cart',$allProducts);//save the item

  }
?>
```

Comment: Please improve the formatting on your post, e.g. use some paragraphs. It's hard to read as it is. Thanks.

Comment: array_search returns the index, which is 0 for the first product. 0 is kinda false. You need a comparison against false here: `if(array_search($id,array_column($allProducts, 'itemid')))` - change it to `if(array_search($id,array_column($allProducts, 'itemid')) !== false)`

Comment: @Jeto thank you for your kind suggestion. :)

Comment: @vins even if this didn't completely solve all your problems, it is defenitely one

Comment: @Jeff Thank you so much. It worked when i used it. also sorry i didn't read your comment completely before...But if you have time can you please let me know whats big difference betwn them?? (of c. your solution is more sensible for me as it worked :) ) Also thank you for answering this quick..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) returns the index, which is 0 for the first product. 0 evaluates to false.
You need a comparison against false here.

Change

```
if(array_search($id,array_column($allProducts, 'itemid'))) { //...
```

to

```
if(array_search($id,array_column($allProducts, 'itemid')) !== false) { //...
```

here's a fiddle that demonstrates this change: https://3v4l.org/m62Ya